CSS preload not working as expected, blocking styles done last
I've been optimizing my new sites page speed and have run into a problem with CSS. Basically I have got a small above-the-fold stylesheet for the first page that is the critical CSS and then I load the non critical (large files) (preloaded) later. However whenever I add in the deferred Bootstrap it doesn't apply the critical styles before hand for some reason, works fine without Bootstrap.
Here is my <head>:
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>

        <!-- Favicons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="48x48">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">

        <!-- This is the critical ABOVE THE FOLD styles THIS SHOULD BE DONE FIRST -->
        <link rel="preload" href="/css/critical/index.css>

        <!-- Custom User Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.min.css">

        <!-- These are the full stylesheets that should load AFTER the critical styles and shouldn't effect CLS. SHOULD BE DONE LAST-->
        <link rel="preload" href="/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css"></noscript>
    
        <link rel="preload" href="/css/style.min.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.min.css"></noscript>


        <!-- Misc other stuff -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/" crossorigin>
        <link fetchpriority="high" rel="preload" as="image" href="/img/opt/under-the-sea.webp" type="image/webp"/>
        <link fetchpriority="high" rel="preload" as="image" href="/img/opt/orcas.jpg" type="image/webp"/>

</head>


I've tried preloading the critical CSS as well and even when it loads and seemingly renders first I still get a big layout shift.
I also tried having internal styles with  tags but then once the Bootstrap and other styles apply they don't take precedence as they are external.
Demo site here: https://cardera-demo.onrender.com/

It seems that the inline css approach can improve the situation. In your case, the CLS is caused by a chain of requests. Also, the fact that the bootstrap styles are deferred does not play in your favour, since the layout is built using it.
So try inlining critical styles in html and preloading the bootstrap styles and take measurements

I have managed to replicate your issue.
When I used the same loading order of CSS as your original, for example, I cannot set the body background-color: var(--bs-body-bg) in index.css it always uses bootstrap.min.css background-color. This is because after preloading, you manually switch rel="preload" to rel="stylesheet" using JavaScript (onload event). At this point, the browser applies the styles from bootstrap.min.css (large CSS file) overriding index.css colors.

When I changed the CSS loading order to preload bootstrap.min.css first and load  the index.css after that. Then that will have the correct body background-color set to the one defined in index.css

I believe CSS specificity is not involved in this behavior but only the order of the CSS loading. The resolution is to load the index.css after the preloaded CSS.
I also noticed duplicate CSS for the body element in index.css there could be others.

Even when I do that I still get the layout shift problem. What I want is the critical index.css to load first and then have the bootstrap.min.css load after and override the styles.

Just quickly, I would advise you not to use inline CSS because if your products are used by companies that use WAF like Cloudflare inline CSS is deemed insecure and moving towards using CSPs that block them. speaking from my own experience. I see a CLS issue it should be fixable.
